# Get value from Option parameter in scala

Tags: scala

I have a parameter

```
case class Envelope(subject: Option[String]) {
}
```

and I want to apply a require function only if subject is non null.

Something like below:

```
require(StringUtils.isNotBlank(subject))
```

Comment: What should happen if the `Option` is empty? You just don't want to run the function?

Comment: In Scala, especially with `Option`s, I fail to see a good reason why `subject` should ever be `null`. An `Envelope` should either have a `subject` (`Some(subjectValue)`) or it does NOT have a `subject` (None). `null` should not come into play!

Comment: `require(subject.exists(StringUtils.isNotBlank(_)))` But as @RandomnessSlayer said, you usually won't have null value in an Option unless you created it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

`Option`s should, from a practical perspective, almost never be null in Scala (I'd argue ***never***, but there are all sorts of compromises and exceptions, especially when working with Java dependencies where `null` checks are more common-place).

With some pre-processing and pattern-matching, you may find this approach acceptable:

```scala
// When working with `Option`s, naming convention usually is "[name_of_var]Opt"
case class Envelope( subjectOpt: Option[String] ) {

    // Utility to check whether or not this `Envelope` has a subject
    def hasSubject: Boolean = subjectOpt.isDefined
    
    // Get the subject or throw an exception if it does not have one (None)
    def getSubject: String = {
        subjectOpt match {
            case None => throw Exception( "Envelope has no subject!" )
            case Some( subject ) => subject
        }
    }
}
    
object Envelope {

    // Utility to create an `Envelope` with no subject
    def apply(): Envelope = Envelope(None)

    // Utility to do a bit of pre-processing, checking for `null` or empty strings
    def apply( subject: String ): Envelope = {
        if ( subject == null || subject.isEmpty ) Envelope()
        else Envelope( Some( subject ) )
    }
}

val nullString: String = null

// Example usages (will have no subject):
val envelopeWithNoSubject: Envelope = Envelope()
val envelopeWithEmptySubject: Envelope = Envelope( "" )
val envelopeWithNullSubject: Envelope = Envelope( nullString )

// envelopeWithNoSubject, ...EmptySubject, and ...NullSubject all return:
... .hasSubject // False
... .getSubject // Exception: Envelope has no subject!

// Example use with subject
val envelopeWithSubject: Envelope = Envelope( "Scala" )

envelopeWithSubject.hasSubject// True
envelopeWithSubject.getSubject // "Scala"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
case class Envelope(subject: Option[String])

def check(en: Envelope): Boolean = {
    require(en.subject.isDefined)
    true
    }
```

It will be finer and you don't have any need to import `StringUtils`.

For fetching the value from `Option` you should go for the `getorElse`. Here we can define the default value for the variable. Ex:

```
def check(str: Option[String]): String = {
  str.getOrElse("")
 }

scala> check(None)
res1: String = ""

scala> check(Some("Test"))
res2: String = Test
```

Only `get` will throw the exception when it will get `None`. Ex:

```
def check(str: Option[String]): String = {
      str.get
     }

scala> check(Some("Test"))
res2: String = Test

scala> check(None)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
  at check(<console>:24)
  ... 48 elided
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go that way:

`subject.map(s => if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(s)) require(s) else s)`

Answer (score -1):

You should be changing the require function call to the following

```
require(StringUtils.isBlank(subject.get))
```

`.get` method returns the string that the `subject` `Option` carries.